# How to identify in a RNA seq data in which sample is in which cell using R using qusage

Tags: r, scrnaseq, bioconductor

I am using RNA seq data and have been using QuSage in R in hopes to try to identify different samples and figure out which cell it belongs to.

I am trying to visualize and utilize the results but I am having trouble doing that. Does anyone have an idea?

---

[QuSAGE](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/23921631/)
Quantitative Set Analysis for Gene Expression method
https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/qusage.html

Comment: Please be more specific. What have you tried, and where are you running into problems?